# PyQt5 Designer with Custom Slots

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt-designer

I'm still trying to figure out PyQt and running into another issue that I've been beating my head over for the last several hours. When I use pyuic5 to convert the .ui file into the .py file, part of the output (in the class Ui_MainWindow) connects signals to slots:

```
self.browseButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.browseSlot)
self.importButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.importSlot)
self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(MainWindow.returnPressedSlot)
```

This is called from the main function:

```
def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = MainWindowUI()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Above this, in the same file, I have the following code:

```
class MainWindowUI(Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = Model()

    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        super().setupUi(mainWindow)

    def debugPrint(self, msg):
        self.textEdit.append(msg)

    def refreshAll(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.model.getFileName())
        self.textEdit.setText(self.model.getFileContents())

    def returnPressedSlot(self):
        self.debugPrint('Return key pressed')

    def importSlot(self):
        self.debugPrint('Import button pressed')

    def browseSlot(self):
        self.debugPrint('Browse button pressed')
```

The exact error I'm getting is this:

```
AttributeError: 'QMainWindow' object has no attribute 'browseSlot'
```

This actually makes perfect sense, because there's no reason `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()` should know anything about the custom slots I defined in the MainWindowUI class. So it makes sense that it doesn't work, but I'm confused about what I should be doing differently. This is how every tutorial I've seen sets it up, so clearly I have a fundamental misunderstanding somewhere. Any help in clarifying this issue would be appreciated!

Many thanks in advance.

---

Edited to add the full code of my `Ui_MainWindow` class:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'test.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.11.3
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(798, 593)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralwidget)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.debugTextBrowser = QtWidgets.QTextBrowser(self.frame_2)
        self.debugTextBrowser.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 351, 461))
        self.debugTextBrowser.setObjectName("debugTextBrowser")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.tab)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.browseButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.browseButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 30, 51, 20))
        self.browseButton.setObjectName("browseButton")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.frame)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 10, 281, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.importButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.importButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(310, 30, 51, 20))
        self.importButton.setObjectName("importButton")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.frame)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(80, 130, 281, 81))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.horizontalLayout_2)
        self.setupProgressBar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar(self.tab)
        self.setupProgressBar.setProperty("value", 0)
        self.setupProgressBar.setTextVisible(False)
        self.setupProgressBar.setInvertedAppearance(False)
        self.setupProgressBar.setTextDirection(QtWidgets.QProgressBar.TopToBottom)
        self.setupProgressBar.setObjectName("setupProgressBar")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.setupProgressBar)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.tab_3 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_3.setObjectName("tab_3")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_3, "")
        self.tab_4 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_4.setObjectName("tab_4")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_4, "")
        self.tab_5 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_5.setObjectName("tab_5")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_5, "")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.tabWidget, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 798, 18))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.browseButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.browseSlot)
        self.importButton.clicked.connect(MainWindow.importSlot)
        self.lineEdit.returnPressed.connect(MainWindow.returnPressedSlot)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.browseButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Browse"))
        self.importButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Import"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("MainWindow", "Setup"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("MainWindow", "Production Forecast"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_3), _translate("MainWindow", "Production Forecast"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_4), _translate("MainWindow", "Page"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_5), _translate("MainWindow", "Page"))
```

Comment: share yout Ui_MainWindow class

Comment: Just updated the initial question to show the full file generated by pyuic5. Also, for what it's worth, this is roughly what I've been following: http://www.science.smith.edu/dftwiki/index.php/PyQt5_Tutorial:_A_Window_Application_with_File_IO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PyQt recommends in your [docs](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html) that you should inherit from the appropriate widget, in this case `QMainWindow`, and use `Ui_MainWindow` as an interface, it is also recommended that you use the decorator `@QtCore.pyqtSlot()` since you save resources and avoid having problems with overloaded signals.

```
class MainWindowUI(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = Model()

    def setupUi(self, mainWindow):
        super().setupUi(mainWindow)

    def debugPrint(self, msg):
        self.textEdit.append(msg)

    def refreshAll(self):
        self.lineEdit.setText(self.model.getFileName())
        self.textEdit.setText(self.model.getFileContents())

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def returnPressedSlot(self):
        self.debugPrint('Return key pressed')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def importSlot(self):
        self.debugPrint('Import button pressed')

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def browseSlot(self):
        self.debugPrint('Browse button pressed')

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindowUI()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The PyQt 5 Designer generates files with **.ui** extension. The file contains xml code which can be converted to Python code with the **pyuic5** command. The pyuic5 command produces a file with **.py** extension.

But each time the pyuic5 command is run, it overwrites any changes made to the Python file. To prevent this we need to copy the "main" code in the generated Python file to a separate file and then use this file as our main program file. In this file we can import the Python class generated by the **pyuic5** command. We can also add our custom slots in this file

This practice of separating Qt Desginer code from custom code is good Qt programming practice. It has been suggested in Section 3 of the video ebook: "[Python GUI Programming Recipes using PyQt5](https://www.packtpub.com/application-development/python-gui-programming-recipes-using-pyqt5-video)".